# cakephp pages never change in browser after CTP file edit

Tags: php, cakephp

After I edit my view ctp files and view the page in the browser. I see no change. I check the file in cpanel as well as ssh and indeed the changes were made.

What am i doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try F5/browsercacherefresh? Does that help? Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try a hard refresh, you might be getting a cached copy of the page.

> Windows : CTRL+F5
>
> MAC: ⇧ Shift and click the Reload button